# Opening file in current directory in java with file protocol

Tags: java, url

I have a license agreement file that needs to be open in default browser.
The file lies in installation folder itself.
I am doing it in java with awt as like this which is working fine:

```
Desktop d=Desktop.getDesktop();
 d.browse(new URI("file://D:/OMS-Install/OMS/oms_license.txt"));
```

But since the entire folder can be placed anywhere on windows drive, at run time I need to consider the current directory. How can I achive this with Java & Default browser of AWT.

Doing it as there is a requirement. I would have otherwise followed many other options to accept terms and conditions.

**Edit**
Adding working code:

```
    String path=new File("OMS/oms_license.txt").getAbsolutePath();
    File license=new File(path);
    URI urlLicense = license.toURI();           
    d.browse(urlLicense);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert get file in current directory and calculate its absolute path

```
new File("./OMS/oms_license.txt").getAbsolutePath()
```

Comment: Yes that helped. Added some extra line with your answer. And that solved my problem. Thanks! Adding working code as Edit to my question.

Comment: Note that it's never a good idea to write Java code and assume that your current directory is correct, or that there even is a current directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Class.getResource()` to retrieve the URL of something on the classpath.

Something along the lines of 
`URL license = getClass().getResource("/OMS/license.txt");`